# Why can't I see user privileges in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 11.8 in AWS RDS and I created a user as below:

```
CREATE USER test WITH LOGIN;
GRANT rds_iam TO test;
```

the code runs success but I can't find the user `test` from:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_privileges where grantee='test';
```

it returns an empty result to me.

I am able to see that user by running

`SELECT *FROM pg_catalog.pg_user where usename='test';`.

Why can't I grant access to the user?

Answer (score 2):

Your `GRANT` statement didn't grant a privilege on a table, it added the user to the role (“group”) `rds_iam`.

User `test` itself doesn't have any privileges on tables, it only inherits them.

`information_schema.table_privileges` will only show the privileges that were granted to a user, not the privileges inherited via role membership.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL command is correct. The problem is on the given role_name. You can get all users by executing the below command

```
SELECT *FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
```

Make sure the given role_name is in the listed role name in the PostgreSQL server. Below the command, you can get users with role

```
SELECT usename AS role_name,
CASE 
  WHEN usesuper AND usecreatedb THEN 
    CAST('superuser, create database' AS pg_catalog.text)
  WHEN usesuper THEN 
     CAST('superuser' AS pg_catalog.text)
  WHEN usecreatedb THEN 
     CAST('create database' AS pg_catalog.text)
  ELSE 
     CAST('' AS pg_catalog.text)
END role_attributes
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
ORDER BY role_name desc;
```

Comment: I am able to see the user name `text` in `pg_user`. But why can't I see the privilege of that user in `information_schema.table_privileges` table?

Comment: Lets try the explanation another way. You **did not grant** any permission to user *test*, you allowed user *test* use the permissions granted to rds_iam. Information_Schema.table_privileges shows **only** permissions granted directly to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL RDS I seen this behavior, where "information_schema.table_privileges" is not getting updated with privileges which granted to any user or role If the table owner is not "dbuser".

So I changed the table owner to "dbuser" immediately it's started showing all the grants which I granted to different users and roles. Not sure how the "Table owner" impacting "table_privileges" view.